# Using Three.js Raycaster to implement a download process of PDF file

Tags: javascript, three.js

How to implement PDF file download process clicking on 3D object in There.js scene?

Here's my code presenting Raycaster's setup:

```
var raycaster;
var mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };

init();

function init() {
    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    renderer.domElement.addEventListener( 'click', raycast, false );
}

function raycast( event ) {    
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );    

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
       var firstIntersectedObject = intersects[ 0 ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your code already works fine. I've just enhanced it with `jsPDF` in order to generate a PDF and then trigger the respective download. The relevant code for this is:

```js
function raycast( event ) {    
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );    

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        const pdf = new jsPDF();
        pdf.text( "Hello world!", 10, 10 );
        pdf.save( "download.pdf" );
    }
}
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/uazj0gr6/1/